# jQuery: My .remove() occurs before .fadeOut() completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get my .fadeout effect to occur and then remove '#all' then run the'genDiv' function. But when I $('.button')click, it seems to jump the .fadeout effect and jump right into my .remove and 'genDiv'. How can I get it is fadeout completely before moving on in the code. I have tried .wait, but maybe I don't quite understand what it does or how it works. Thanks so much. Here is my code snippet:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $('#all').fadeOut(2000)
   $('#all').remove()
   genDivs()
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `fadeOut`: https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback:

```
$('#all').fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $('#all').remove()
    genDivs() 
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Can you explain what exactly is going on here. A bit new to JS, what is callback?